# What is the best way to insert million record in sequelize

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

What is the best way to insert a million record using sequelize, Currently I am using bulkCreate but it's very slow and didn't finish.

so do you think that there's a way to do it.

```
return dbmyTable.bulkCreate(array, {transaction: t}).then(function (item) {
       return res.jsonp('Done');
})
```

Comment: The best and perhaps the only practical way to insert a million records into mysql is with LOAD DATA INFILE.

Comment: Anything is possible but the question is whether it is practical.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same issue using PostgreSQL and agree with @e4c5 that some built-in database method is best for this.  The problem is that you're loading all the data into memory until the bulkCreate executes.  If you got a million rows, you'll probably run out of memory before it even executes.  Even still, if you queue it up using something like [async.cargo](https://github.com/caolan/async#cargo), you'll still be waiting for the db to get back to you all while the data asyncrhonously consumes all your memory.

My solution was to ditch sequelize for the loading of data (at least until they implement streaming or something (see their [github issue #2454](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/2454))).  I ended up creating [db-streamer](https://github.com/djstroky/db-streamer), but it just has pg support for now.  You'll want to look at [streamsql](https://github.com/brianloveswords/streamsql) for mysql.